# Using proxy, only for a specific server certificate

Tags: c#, proxy, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, titanium-web-proxy

In Titanium-Web-Proxy is possible to exclude Https addresses you don't want to proxy. The examples use the OnBeforeTunnelConnectRequest for this, but at this moment only the request is known.

```
private async Task OnBeforeTunnelConnectRequest(object sender, TunnelConnectSessionEventArgs e)
{
    string hostname = e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host;
    await WriteToConsole("Tunnel to: " + hostname);

    if (hostname.Contains("dropbox.com"))
    {
        // Exclude Https addresses you don't want to proxy
        // Useful for clients that use certificate pinning
        // for example dropbox.com
        e.DecryptSsl = false;
    }
}
```

But I need to get information from the server certificate to exclude the address. I can get the server certificate only in `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, but at this moment I can not exclude the address. How can this be done?